# Is there any Python syntax highlighter for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, ironpython, syntax-highlighting

When I used Visual Studio 2008 I could install [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=IronPython) + [IronPython Integrated IDE](http://ironpythonstudio.codeplex.com/) + [Visual Studio Shell Integrated Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=40646580-97FA-4698-B65F-620D4B4B1ED7&displaylang=en) and then my Visual Studio would parse .py files and highlight its syntax.

I tried the same with Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 with no success. Where is the catch? Should I wait a bit longer for new releases or there is a shortcut?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[Python Tools for Visual Studio 2010](http://pytools.codeplex.com/)**

[IronPython.Net](http://ironpython.net/)

<strike>**This Extension is no longer available. See Jeff Hardy's comment below.**</strike>

Try IronPython Extensions for VisualStudio 2010:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/a0ffaffc-d1c2-4b6c-a9d1-3addc37a5673

Comment: It worked, and this solution works even if you only have VS2010 (no IronPython etc)

Comment: The above link doesn't seem to be working, can you please fix it?

Comment: Those extensions only supported VS 2010 Beta 2. The IronPython team will be releasing their own extensions for VS 2010 RTM within the next couple of weeks.

Comment: They produced new extensions for RTM, it's on CTP3 now, a vsix file.

Comment: The location of the .vsix file that Shimmy mentions is here -- http://ironpython.net/tools/download/

Answer (score 9):

Here is the latest update (July 2011):

[Python Tools for Visual Studio 2010](http://pytools.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jesse99/Linguist does the job, too. Horrible style settings, but it works great.